# 1 old (Snow Leopard) iMac & 2 newer (Mountain Lion) MacBooks -- iCloud or DropBox?

Tags: icloud, dropbox, macos

I have an old iMac (circa 2006, Intel Core Duo) which is running Snow Leopard (somewhat slowly) and cannot be upgraded to Mountain Lion, so there's no iCloud on that machine.

I also have 2 MacBook Pros which will both be running Mountain Lion very shortly.

My question is, I'd like to keep my "Documents" folder in sync across all of these three machines.  If I used iCloud to sync both MacBooks, is there an easy way to sync the iMac (minus iCloud) as well?

Or should I just use DropBox?  Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I think in your case Dropbox is the solution to keep synchronized your files.

You can continue to use iCloud on your other Mac with Moutain Lion (to synchronize your reminders or other contents that use iCloud).

Moreover, my understanding is that iCloud don't sync your Documents folder, so anyway for your need, you should use Dropbox.

However, be careful when you put your personal data online !

Comment: Thanks for that.  I just assumed iCloud would sync the "Documents" folder too, but you're right, privacy is an issue.  Any suggestions for syncing "Documents" folders across all three macs without hitting the web?

Comment: @RobertHume You can use a solution with a local server or use another alternative to Dropbox that is more secure, see [this article](http://lifehacker.com/5818908/dropbox-vs-the-alternatives-which-online-syncing-service-is-right-for-you) for a good comparison between several services.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend ChronoSync. You can use it to sync just one file or a whole folder (even your entire Documents Folder) between two Macs over your local network. You can sync one way (left to right, say) or both ways (ie. with changes in both folders). It can be set up to run automatically when a volume mounts, or manually.